# Enabling TeX in an answer

Tags: mathjax

I searched but didn't find basic information on enabling TeX in an answer. $...$ didn't seem to work.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: This should be done in meta, not in the main site. To use LaTeX, just use `$...$` or `$$...$$` (as well as a handful of other commands such as `\begin{align*}` and the like). The site should do it automatically.

Comment: @Arturo, sorry, I was in meta but the puter choked and I lost my page.

Comment: @Arturo, tried again to ask a question in meta, but this time got message that I my rep was too low.

Comment: @Thomas McLeod: I've asked that the question be migrated; but in any case, I don't understand what your question *is*. You simply type LateX and the site should "enable" it. *You* don't have to do anything other than just type.

Comment: @Arturo, may it's a problem with my browser (IE8). I need to press refresh serveral times before I see the TeX source slowing rendering.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: If you are getting `[math processing error]`, then you need to do a cache-clear; `shift-refresh` does it in Firefox, I don't know how to do it with Internet Explorer.

Comment: @Thomas: In my experience MathJax is unusable in IE8 (as you describe). But it works fine in Chrome or Firefox. Has anyone got MathJax working nicely in IE?

Comment: @Thomas: yes, unfortunately, there is a reputation threshold for asking questions on Meta. The number is quite low, you should be able to surpass it in no time!

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the [answer that you gave](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16890/stirling-numbers-of-the-second-kind-on-multiset/18795#18795) on a question on the main site, you already know the syntax and had input the LaTeX codes correctly.

If your question is not about the actual input of the TeX content, please edit/comment on the question to clarify.

Comment: I wasn't sure what was happening. I know how to use Latex. But the source appears as is, unless I refreshed (F5) at least once.

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, that's a local problem with your browser, not the site. As Bill notes, IE seems to be particularly nasty to MathJax.

Comment: I enabled debugging in IE and get this error in the MathJax script: Line: 35
Error: No such element

Comment: The error goes away after several refreshes.

Comment: @Thomas: A race condition in IE maybe? MathJax inserts elements to the webpage, and IE8 is notoriously slow with it. Try the following: set the [compatibility view](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/features/easier.aspx) in IE8 to enable IE7 compatible emulation. I dunno if it will help, but according to MathJax's website this may help.

Comment: @Willie, IE8 Compatibility View does not help.